# Overheating engine

Tags: ford, overheating, radiator

Overheating engine. I Recently took my 1959 Ford Skyliner to a mechanic To fix transmission and engine leaks. In addition, the mechanic installed power brakes and changed my generator out for a 90 amp alternator. Since then, my car Overheats. The gauge goes past the H sign Even after driving for a few miles. Is there any correlation between the work that was done in my car now overheating excessively? The car only has 2000 miles on it. Original rebuilt engine.

I recently bought a new radiator just in case that will do the trick.

Comment: Solar Mike, forgive me. I’m new to this website. I can see your answer to my question but I am unable to open it. I can only see part of what you wrote. How do I see the entire answer?

Comment: Is the radiator full of coolant? check when engine is cold.

Comment: 2k on the rebuilt engine? Did they replace the water pump? Or the radiator? Have you checked the radiator for flow?

Comment: Yes. I meant 90amp Alternator. 

I did It looks like there is flow but the mechanic

Comment: The initial mechanic did the following work: Fixed leak from coolant temperature sensor, valve cover gaskets and fuel pump. power steering reseal. The transmission pan gasket and rear tail shaft seal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! First thing I'd do is ensure there is enough coolant in the radiator.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. There is enough coolant in the radiator.